# how to not get duplicate data in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query in which i am fetching details from two tables now i want data of users whose requests are pending and from other data centers i want the pin codes that they have so i made this query which is working fine but it is giving me duplicate data for name and center too. this is my query

```
$sql = "
SELECT u.username
     , u.district
     , u.requests
     , c.username
     , c.id 
  FROM users u
  JOIN center c
    ON u.username = c.username 
 where u.requests = 'pending'
";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)  {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name = $row['username'];
    $district = $row['district'];
    $center = $row['id'];?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $row['username']?></td><td><?php echo $row['district']?></td><td><?php echo $row['id']?></td></tr>

    <?php
}
}
     ?>
```

The following provides a text representation of current output for better understanding.

```
name  center pin code
dhruv mumbai 5545454
dhruv mumbai 2618165165
```

I want the $center variable in commas and don't want it to repeat the name and district variable, so something like this:

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) *" for providing example data andexpected results...  *"how to not get duplicate data in php mysql"* Define *"duplicate data"* as you can have complete row duplicates which spans all columns as *"duplicate data"* .. Or *"duplicate data"* which span one or more columns in SQL tables or resultsets..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get a comma separated list of values. Change your query to

```
$sql = "
SELECT u.username
     , u.district
     , u.requests
     , GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) AS id
  FROM users u
  JOIN center c
    ON u.username = c.username 
 where u.requests = 'pending'
GROUP BY u.username
       , u.district
       , u.requests";
```

Note I have removed `c.username` from the `SELECT` list as it is the same value as `u.username` (because of the `JOIN` condition) and since it has the same column name it will overwrite `u.username` in the output data.

Comment: But why would you, given that you're parsing the array anyway?

Comment: @Strawberry as I understand the question, OP wants output of `dhruv mumbai 5545454,2618165165` so this will remove any need to parse. Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: In PHP, if you want to display a result set then you need to parse it... I guess it comes down to personal preference, but unless used in conjunction with other aggregating functions (MAX/MIN/AVG) then, to my mind, there is  no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) need be part of the solution.

Comment: @Strawberry gotcha. To me it's easier to do this than trying to figure out in PHP whether two of the values in the current row are the same as the previous row or not.

Comment: But it's so much less flexible then just returning atomized data - anyway, just my 2c.

Comment: @Strawberry agreed. This is only preferable if all you're doing is displaying the data.